# ASP.NET Core receive SignalR updates

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I know SignalR is not available for ASP.NET Core 1.1 and in preview for 2.0. Meantime I need to work around this limitation.

The application I'm building is an ASP.NET Core 1.1 MVC application. One small but important feature in this application is case management. The view needs to be updated with new incoming cases for that specific user.

My SignalR 2 hub runs in a separate ASP.NET 4.* application.

I was hoping as this is all 1-way that I could easily use the SignalR JavaScript client instead of the .NET client and Bob is your uncle. 
The problem however is AuthN/AuthZ for which I'm using Azure AD B2C (oauth2)

Within the MVC app I use standard cookie authorization, but the pattern I'm using for the backend API's is that I use my MVC code to wrap the access token in a bearer tokens and sent that to the backend API where I use jwt bearer  authorization. Therefore my clientside JavaScript never sees the access token, just the cookies that the MVC app uses between View and Controller.

The problem now is that if I want to connect to the Hub using JavaScript I have nothing to sent to the Hub to prove my identity as the jwt token only exists in the MVC host, and the cookies are HTTP Only so inaccessible.

Any ideas or alternatives?

Thanks!

Comment: Within your backend services, why are you using auth. Use http or https with firewalled ip instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found it! I can use the following method to pass along the cookie from my MVC app:

1. Follow instructions in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/compatibility/cookie-sharing to setup cookie sharing
2. Use the withCredentials=true on XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials through the start method on the hubConnection in SignalR

   conn.start({ withCredentials: true }).done(function () { 
       hub.invoke('recordHit');
   });
3. Setup CORS in the Hub project.

easy! Works like a charm